# Data Scraping: How to select width from a style tag by using Scrapy CSS?

Tags: css, python-2.7, css-selectors, scrapy

I'm new to learn `scrapy`these days. I'm trying to select `width` from a `div` by using `CSS Selector`, but its not being possible for me. I tried a lot to find out solution, but every time i fond solution with `xpath` instead of `css` selector.

The `HTML` code is:

```
<div class="stars-container">
   <div class="stars" style="width: 60.606%"> Rating</div>
</div>
```

After getting `response` by `scrapy shell URL`, my attempts to select **`width`** from the above `html` is:

```
response.css('.stars-container .stars ::attr(width)')
response.css('.stars-container  ::attr(width)')
```

It'll be great pleasure for me to learn it easily if someone help me out in this problem. **Thank You**

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get just the width value and insist on pure CSS solution, here you go:

```
response.css('.stars-container .stars::attr(style)').re_first('width:\s*(\d+\.\d+)\s*%')
```

Comment: Thank you @Tomas for your contribution. It'll really prove good for me.

Answer (score 0):

It can be help for your.

```
 response.css(".stars-container .stars").xpath('@style').extract()
```

Comment: Thank You @rana, for showing your interest to solve this query.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can get width.

```
response.css('.stars-container .stars ::attr(style)').re_first(r'width:\s+(\d+.\d+)')
```

Also get comfortable with python regx liberary you can find documentation here [Python re](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html)

Comment: Thank you @afraz for the solution. Can you please explain what's the purpose of `.re_first(r':\s+(\d+.\d+)')` ? It'll really helpful for me.

Comment: Scrapy uses re library internally. In this method, we are telling that look for ":" in the string then any no of spaces after that then look for any number of digits followed by a comma and any number of digits. re_first will return only first  matching case . please also see that all expressions inside " () " will be selected

Comment: Thank You @AfrazAhmad to provide guidance.